# Node js not connected with MySQL new created database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to connect NodeJS with MySQL database.I am using WAMP. It's connected only default database like "mysql"and"information_schema" but those databases i created not connect with NodeJs and given me following error.
Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Code

```
**Server.js**
----------
const express = require("express");
const app    = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 
const mysql = require("mysql");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : "localhost",
    user     : "root", //User Name
    password : "",  // No password
    database : "techbiz", // Database Name
    multipleStatements:true

  });

  connection.connect((err)=>{
      if(!err)
      {
          console.log("Database connected ");
      }
      else{
console.log(err)      }
  })

// Initialize port

const PORT =  process.env.PORT || 5000;

// send rquest to web page

app.get('/',(req,res) => res.send(`Automize Business Solution running on :${PORT}`));

app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log("Server is running"));




 [Database][1]

**Error**
----------
Server is running
{ Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'techbiz'
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (K:\WebProjects\MySQL\abs-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (K:\WebProjects\MySQL\abs-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (K:\WebProjects\MySQL\abs-
    at Socket.<anonymous> (K:\WebProjects\MySQL\abs-
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
  code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
  errno: 1049,
  sqlMessage: 'Unknown database \'techbiz\'',
  sqlState: '42000',
  fatal: true }






  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9MSc.png
```

Thanks

Comment: Error     **Error**
    ----------
    Server is running
    { Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'techbiz'
        at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (K:\WebProjects\MySQL\abs-server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
        at Handshake.ErrorPacket (K:\WebProjects\MySQL\abs-s       at Functio
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
      code: 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR',
      errno: 1049,
      sqlMessage: 'Unknown database \'techbiz\'',
      sqlState: '42000',
      fatal: true }

Comment: Well have you created the database named `techbiz`? That's what the error literally tells you - you need to create the database before you can connect to it.

Comment: I already created techbiz

Comment: Does this user have privileges to the techbiz table? Are there possibly multiple MySQL servers running?

Comment: no just have one mysql server running.

Comment: If you try to connect to the db via the mysql cli, does it work? `mysql -h localhost -u root techbiz`

Comment: Yes, it is connected.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib  Your code is working. I have tested. WAMP sometimes gives troubles. my advice is install XAMPP. and you can use app.use(Express.json()); instead of body-parser as well.

Answer (score 0):

i just change my wamp version and using MySQL 5.5.8 , and now same code working fine.
thanks